# Validating data entered by the user in php

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I want to validate the data that entered by the user to mysql database.
So, the user cannot enter letters in the fields that required numbers.
And after validating the data should be entered into the database.
I have written that code, but it is not working.. it accepts letters for number fields

```
<?php
include 'testinput.php';
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DATABASE");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect";
        }  

        $card1 = test_input($_POST['card']);
        $first1= $_POST['first'];
        $last1=  $_POST['last'];
        $id1 = test_input($_POST['id']);
        $mob1 = test_input($_POST['mobile']);
        $vis1 = test_input($_POST['visit']);

        $query = "INSERT INTO aftness1_clients.clients (card, first, last, id, mobile, visit) VALUES ('$card1','$first1','$last1','$id1', '$mob1','$vis1')";

        if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)){
            echo "Error ". mysqli_error($con);
            echo "<br>";
        }
        $newrecord ="<b>One client added Successfully !</b>";

}// end of main if


?>


<html>
    <header>
        <title>
            Add a Client
        </title>
    </header>
<body bgcolor="#F0FFFF">
<br/> <br/> <center><font size="5" color="#4EE2EC">  Clients Information </font> </center> <br/>
<b>All fields are required:</b> <br/> <br/>

    <form action = "insert.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>
        <fieldset>

            <legend>New Client</legend>
            <lable><font size="3" color="#38ACEC"><b>Card Number:</b></font></lable>   
            <input type="text" STYLE="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;" size="10" maxlength="30" name="card"/><br/>
            <lable><font size="3" color="#38ACEC"><b>First Name:</b></font></lable>    
            <input type="text" STYLE="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;" size="10" maxlength="30" name="first"/><br/>
            <lable><font size="3" color="#38ACEC"><b>Last Name:</b></font></lable>     
            <input type="text" STYLE="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;" size="10" maxlength="30" name="last"/><br/>
            <lable><font size="3" color="#38ACEC"><b>ID Number:</b></font></lable>     
            <input type="text" STYLE="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;" size="10" maxlength="30" name="id"/><br/>
            <lable><font size="3" color="#38ACEC"><b>Mobile Number:</b></font></lable> 
            <input type="text" STYLE="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;" size="10" maxlength="30" name="mobile"/><br/>
            <lable><font size="3" color="#38ACEC"><b>Visits:</b></font></lable> 
            <input type="text" STYLE="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;" size="10" maxlength="30" name="visit"/><br/>
        </fieldset>
        </br>
            <font color="#FFFFFF"> <input type ="Submit" name="submit" value = "Add" align="right"/></font>
    </form>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
echo $newrecord
?>
</body>
</html>

<br/><br/><br/>
<a href="index.php">Main Page</a>
```

and this is the testinput function

```
<?php
function test_input($data)
{
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

Where is the problem in my code, and is there any other way to check the validation of the data?

Comment: where you have validations? you need to use regex or is_int() for validate numeric values

Comment: Please don't use `stripslashes()` on random input. It'll just corrupt it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this one for validation ctype_alpha only checks for the letters  [A-Za-z]
or preg_match ("/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/",$data).

Answer (score 0):

you need to validate your input data with regex or php numeric check function  like
[is_int()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) or [is_numeric()](https://www.php.net/is_numeric)

```
function test_input($data)
{
  $data = trim($data);
  if(is_int($data)) {
    return $data;  
  }
  else {
    //do your stuff  may be redirect to again input page and display error msg.
  }
}
```

using regex :-

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $str)) {
  // contains only 0-9
} else {
  // contains other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a php class I wrote for validations like this. Feel free to use it!

```
<?php
class filterInput {

    public function __construct() {


    }

    public function filterAllButNumbers($string) {

        return $this->returnedValue($string, preg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $string));

    }

    public function filterAllButLetters($string) { 

        return $this->returnedValue($string, preg_replace("[^A-Za-z]", "", $string));

    }

    public function filterAllButNumbersAndSpaces($string) {

        return $this->returnedValue($string, preg_replace("[^0-9 ]", "", $string));

    }

    public function filterAllButLettersAndSpaces($string) {

        return $this->returnedValue($string, preg_replace("[^A-Za-z ]", "", $string));

    }

    public function filterAllButNumbersAndLetters($string) {

        return $this->returnedValue($string, preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $string));

    }

    public function filterAllButNumbersLettersAndSpaces($string) {

        return $this->returnedValue($string, preg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $string));

    }

    public function filterHex($string) {

        return $this->returnedValue($string, preg_replace("[^A-Fa-f0-9]", "", $string));

    }

    public function filterSlashes($string) {

        return $this->returnedValue($string, stripSlashes($string));

    }

    public function filterTags($string) {

        return $this->returnedValue($string, strip_tags($string));

    }

    public function filterEmail($email) {
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function filterLength($string, $minimum, $maximum) {

        if(strlen($string) >= $minimum && strlen($string) <= $maximum) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function boolify($filteredString) {
        if(strcmp($filteredString, "true") == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private function returnedValue($string, $filteredString) {
        if (strcmp($string, $filteredString) != 0) {
            return $filteredString;
        } else {
            return "true";
        }

    }


}





?>
```

It returns true (in string form) if the string matches the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Do some Javascript Validations in your code

Here Have a simple example ;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
    <html lang="en">  
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                font-size: 9pt;
                font-family: Arial;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        Numeric Value: <input type="text" id="text1" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" />
        <span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Input digits (0 - 9)</span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var specialKeys = new Array();
            specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
            function IsNumeric(e) {
                var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
                var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
                document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
                return ret;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope it will helps you !